# How to select multiple slicer items of one slicer with different checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, items, slicers

My purpose: In a sheet of my file, there is a list of checkboxes that I can check in order to select specific sliceritems of the slicer 'A' located in another sheet of my file.

I succeeded to write a code in order select a slicer item of the slicer 'A' once I have selected the checkbox (for example when I click in the checkboxe 'RD' it select the slicer item 'RD' in the slicer 'A')

However, I can't select multiple slicer items of one slicer with dthe checkboxes

I tried to write a code to select one slicer item at once and it's working. When I click on a checkboxe in my sheet 'Report', the item of a slicer in a worksheet of my workbook is well selected

I tried this code

```
Sub CheckBox105_Click()

Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim department(0 To 21) As Variant

Set sC = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Department")

Application.EnableEvents = False

For i = 0 To 21
   department(i) = sC.SlicerItems(i + 1).Name
Next i

sC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = department

            sC.SlicerItems("RR").Selected = True
            sC.SlicerItems("FD").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("HG").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("BP").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("HH").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("CO").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("CO").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("YH").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("LI").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("ED").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("FI").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("GM").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("GU").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("HR").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("IT").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("LE").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("OP").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("RK").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("SRG").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("BRM").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("DT").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("IC").Selected = False
            sC.SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

With this code, the result that I expect is the following one: 
I select the checkboxe105 and it select the slicer item 'RD'
I select the checkoxe106 and it select the slicer item 'FD' and keep the first slicer item 'RD' selected

Comment: I don't know why are you using checkboxes but i'd put the items you want to select into a dictionary, clear all the filters on the slicer and then loop through the slicers: `For Each SI in SC.VisibleSlicerItems` and then `If Not Dictionary.Exists(SI.Name) Then SI.Selected = False`

Comment: Hi Damian, I followed your advise and the code is not working, could you please provide me more details about what you told me ? I am not familiar with this code, thanks a lot !

Comment: I did this code , but it is still not working : Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim si As sliceritem
Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary

Set sC = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Department")
        
dict.Add Key:="GB", Item:=8
dict.Add Key:="GM", Item:=9

sC.ClearManualFilter

For Each si In sC.VisibleSlicerItems
    If Not dict.Exists(si.Name) Then si.Selected = False
Next

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Starting VBA so delete this question for misunderstanding/not understanding problem.

Can you use your array / loop along with .SlicerItems(index OR Name).Selected = True.  Note will need to write something to un-select slicer items when unchecked.

Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Product")
    .SlicerItems("Baby Clothes").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Diamonds").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Hats").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Kid Activities").Selected = True
End With
```

Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Product")
    .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
End With
```

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Product")
    .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
    .SlicerItems(2).Selected = True
End With
```

Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Product")
    .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
    .SlicerItems(2).Selected = True
    .SlicerItems(3).Selected = True
End With
```

End Sub

'Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
'    'Select/unselect Hats checkbox
'    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
'        Call AddHats
'    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then
'        Call RemoveHats
'    Else
'        MsgBox "Help"
'    End If
'
'End Sub

Answer (score 0):

And wouldn't it be easier to copy the slicer onto the sheet instead of using checkboxes? Perhaps you are unaware that the SlicerCache can have several Slicers, even on different sheets. Each Slicer is a shape, and when one is modified, all are modified, because the SlicerCache they depend on is modified. Thus, when you select a SlicerItem in its sheet's Slicer, it is also selected in the original sheet's Slicer.